# Solve IVP with the method of characteristics (quasilinear PDE) (+shockwaves)

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristic-functions, initial-value-problems

The question i just can't figure out one bit is:

Solve for the continious function $u(x,t)$:
$$u_t+(1-2u)u_x=0 $$
$$-\infty < x < \infty, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{for} & x < 0 \\  \frac{3}{4} & \mbox{for} & x>0\end{matrix}\right.$$

a.) solve for $u(x,t)$ (clarify in pictures how the solution evolves in time)

b.) Determine $u(x,t)$ if the IVs change to:
$$u(x,0)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{for} & x > 0 \\  \frac{3}{4} & \mbox{for} & x<0\end{matrix}\right.$$

I know you probably should start of like this:

$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

If $ \frac{dx}{dt}=(1-2u)$ then $\frac{du}{dt} =0$

So $x = t - 2u(x_0,0)t + x_0$ with $x_0=x(t)$

Rewrite $x_0 = x - t + 2u(x_0,0)t$.

Use IVs with $x=x_0$:

$u(x_0,0)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{for} & x_0 < 0 \\  \frac{3}{4} & \mbox{for} & x_0>0\end{matrix}\right.$

$u(x_0,0)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{for} & x - t + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}t < 0 \\  \frac{3}{4} & \mbox{for} & x - t + 2\cdot \frac{3}{4}t>0\end{matrix}\right.$

$u(x,t)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{for} & x < \frac{1}{2}t \\  \frac{3}{4} & \mbox{for} & x>-\frac{1}{2}t\end{matrix}\right.$

And from here on out i'm just completely blank.

Comment: Would you please let me know which book you're following?

Comment: Chapter 12.6 from Richard Haberman - Applied Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems (5th)

Comment: But this problem is invented by our professor. There's no example, or exercise using a $(1+u)$ term as $\frac{dx}{dt}$